# Linux. Shell. Sh. Копирование файлов

Tags: linux, shell

Здравствуйте, господа. Хотелось бы получить совет или помощь.

Задача такова - пользователь вводит имя скрипта, допустим, "`my_copy`" и список параметров (все еще в командной строке): неограниченный список файлов - директория 1 - директория 2. Допустим:

```
my_copy a.c b.c a1.c b1.c /dir1 /dir2
```

реализовать функцию копирования введённых файлов из dir1 в dir2. Собственно проблема моя такова, что я не знаю, как считывать параметры не с начала, а с конца. Число параметров я узнать могу, а как считать последний или предпоследний - не знаю.

Ну и если кто-то обладает довольно высоким уровнем и культурой написания красивых скриптов, киньте примерчик, допустим, по этой задаче. Посмотреть на общий стиль оформления и общепринятые пути решения. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Два последних параметра можно получить, например, так

```
a1=${!#} #последний
a=$(($#-1))
a2=${!a} #предпоследний

echo "Last: \"$a1\", before last: \"$a2\""
```

Все-таки shell - очень странный язык

Comment: Классно, вообще не знал о такой подстановке.

Comment: Сам с трудом вспомнил. Давно на шеле не писал.

Answer (score 3):

Покрутил так-сяк, ничего лучше (самому не очень нравится) не придумал. Но, без shift и пробелы в значениях параметров не мешают.

```
if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    let last=$#
    let plast=$last-1
    echo nargs =  $# lastno = $last plastno = $plast
    namel=`echo $# | awk '{printf "${%s}",$1}'`
    vlast=`eval echo $namel`
    namepl=`echo $plast | awk '{printf "${%s}",$1}'`
    vplast=`eval echo $namepl`
    echo last arg = \'$vlast\'   before-last = \'$vplast\'
else
    echo not enought
fi
```

Имена дурацкие, но думаю идея с `eval` ясна.

**UPD** [[@myqck](/users/9236/myqck)](/users/9236/myqck), прочел Ваш вопрос повнимательней. Посмотрите на копирование. **Не уверен**, что это *общепринятый образец*, но IMHO работает.

```
#!/bin/sh
# copy files from dir1 to dir2
#

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo Usage: my-cp dir1 dir2 dir1-filenames-list
    exit 1
fi

dir1=$1; shift
dir2=$1; shift

#echo dir1 = \'$dir1\' dir2 = \'$dir2\' files: $*

if [ -d $dir1 ]; then
# Это по желанию. Если dir2 должно существовать, выкиньте 
#  и поправьте echo в if
    mkdir -p $dir2
    if [ ! -d $dir2 ]; then
    echo Can\'t create $dir2
    exit 2
    fi
# copy files with user,permitions,times ...
    (cd $dir1; tar cf - $*) | (cd $dir2; tar xf -)

# другой вариант с cp
#    dir2=`(cd $dir2; pwd)`
#    cd $dir1;
#    cp -R $* $dir2
else
    echo No source directory: $dir1
    exit 1
fi
```

Может быть окажется Вам полезным. Для упрощения программирования я изменил порядок аргументов и разрешил копирование иерархии (если есть оглавления в списке копируемых файлов)

```
my-cp source-dir target-dir files-list-in-source-dir
```

IMHO так тоже достаточно удобно для пользователя. Если target нет, попробуем сделать его.

Если копирование иерархии Вам принципиально не подходит, то просто используйте вариант копирования с `cp` и выкиньте -R.

Для варианта с tar придется модифицировать список (бежите по нему, проверяете тип файла  и если элемент это не файл, то делаете shift).

Comment: А что, shift -- это самое главное зло на Земле?

    #!/bin/bash
    declare -a arr
    for((i=0;$#>2;i++)) do
        arr[$i]=$1
        shift
    done
    echo ${arr[@]}
    echo $1 $2

В arr -- значения параметров (с пробелами, если есть). Как уж их потом маскировать -- вопрос другой.

Comment: @alexlz, зло? Ну, что Вы...

Просто мне самому стало интересно вспомнить, как можно вытащить i-ый аргумент, не трогая остальных.

Answer (score 2):

Уровень и культура... Где ж их взять-то? Вобщем -- не знаю. Но если нет пробелов в параметрах, то можно присвоить массиву (если есть, то несколько сложнее), а уж там-то -- по индексам -1 и -2

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=($@)
echo ${arr[-1]} ${arr[-2]}
```

Но если нужны два последних (без предшествующих), то можно

```
#!/bin/bash
shift $(($#-2))
echo $1 $2
```